# pass list of values from html button to python scripts

Tags: python, html, django

i have a html template like:

```
<button id="demo-btn-" >Pack</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'no')"></th>
            <th>Invoice</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Order date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Tracking Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for oid,dbd,stts,tp in new_orders %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="{{oid}}"></td>
            <td><a class="btn-link" href="#">{{oid}}</a></td>
            <td>Steve N. Horton</td>
            <td><span class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{dbd}} </span></td>
            <td>{{tp}}</td>
            <td>{{stts}}</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when i select the checkbox in `<thead>` all the checkboxes in `<tbody>` are selected. Now i want, when i select the checkbox and press the pack button, the oid value for each row should be passed to a django view. How to do that?

EDIT:

I want to pass multiple oids as a list to python script. I can do that if i can pass these as a list to django app's views file. I dont know how to pass a list or a value to a django application.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you wrap this code in a `<form>` element and make the button a submit one, what you describe will already happen. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: you can use serialization for your form values before form gets submitted